# Codeigniter URL routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Probably, there are tons of results in google and stackoverflow. But unfortunately I could not get anything to work so far.

What I have --
`http://localhost/profile/user/userA/12345`

What I want --
`http://localhost/profile/user/userA`

in the URL

Conditions

- Need to parse the result with 12345 and URL should be
  `http://localhost/profile/user/userA`

The result of the page is being displayed with data provided by the last segment i.e 12345, in the query

Comment: show your code what you tried ?

Comment: profile is the controller, user is the method. userA and 12345 are the segments I am passing via a link, and in controller profile-method user, I catch that using $this->uri->segment(4) and pass that in my query. What I want is the logic what is present should be kept but the url should change from profile/user/userA/12345 to profile/user/userA

Comment: `12345 ` is it the id which will be change with user ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share my code. What I commented before is exactly how I am doing. I actually want to route the url to the desired one mentioned but need the 12345 to process my query. 12345 should not appear in the URL.

Comment: So you should send `12345` in other way to this function with `post` method

Comment: Preferably GET, but POST would do, if you could help me with this. I am using <a href> attribute to navigate to other page

Comment: is `userA` unique in DB?

Comment: or you can use session also

Comment: yes userA is unique

Comment: by clicking on anchor use ajax and send data to your function or use set session on your page where you have anchor and get sesion on your desired function or page .

Comment: @OwaisArain is right - just use Post. You can make it look like whatever you want. Use codeigniter form helper to simplify the addressing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Short of using `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL (which I am not sure would be possible and personally would not want to attempt) there isn't a way to pass data via URI segments and hide those segments in the browser address line.

Codeigniter's routing isn't going to help. URI Routing does not change the displayed URL. That isn't what it is for and actually it's just the opposite.

Routing is for reinterpreting the URL to call a different controller and, optionally, method and, optionally, argument segments. The arguments must still be provided however and will still be displayed in the browser's address line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage. 
Before you are redirecting to this page `http://localhost/profile/user/userA`

save 12345 in session.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id',12345);
```

you can retrieve this by

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');
```